# Reclassifying raster after image classification in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, reclassify, image-classification

In the ArcGIS Pro Imagery tab, there is the possibility to reclassify an image after classification to manually change misclassified pixels to their correct values, however, after doing this, my pixel values in the count are not changing to reflect the modifications I have done.

How can I update the counts to reflect the modifications?

Comment: you can try https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-statistics.htm

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have thematic raster after classification. Usually, post classification correction involves, **Majority Filter**, **Boundary Clean**, **Region Group**, **Thresholding**(< specified area), or Nibble. You can access these tools under Generalization toolset under Spatial Analyst Toolbox.

For more information you can refer to [Generalization of classified raster imagery](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/generalization-of-classified-raster-imagery.htm) in the ArcGIS Pro Online Help.